# Linq to XML with Namespace Prefix Not Working

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have been working from Scott Allen's [Puralsight course on Linq Fundamentals](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=linq-fundamentals-csharp-6&author=scott-allen&name=linq-fundamentals-csharp-6-m6&clip=5&mode=live) and this linked section describes reading xml with Namespace prefixes, yet I'm not able to make this work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<OutboundEvent
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:abb.com:assetsuite:IF:Event http://apifw/devifa/xml/GeneralLedger/GeneralLedger.Publish.Event.V940.xsd"
    xmlns="urn:abb.com:assetsuite:IF:Event"
    xmlns:hdr="urn:abb.com:assetsuite:IF:Header"
    xmlns:bo="urn:abb.com:assetsuite:IF:BO"
    xmlns:boe="urn:abb.com:assetsuite:IF:IFExtension"
>
...
    <bo:BusinessObject>
    ...
    </bo:BusinessObject>
</OutboundEvent>
```

I should be getting a single XElement returned from the following code, yet I am not:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(path);
var bo = (XNamespace)"urn:abb.com:assetsuite:IF:BO";

var businessobjects =
    from elements in document.Element("OutboundEvent")?.Elements(bo + "BusinessObject") 
        ?? Enumerable.Empty<XElement>()
    select elements;
```

Comment: Don't take a screenshot of _text_... post the actual text.

Comment: What is the best way to paste in XML which spans several pages then?

Comment: Paste the relevant parts of the XML, it doesn't need to be the full text. Just enough to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I prefer getting namespace in code rather than hard coding.              XElement root = document.root;
            XNamespace bo = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("bo");

Comment: @jdweng doing that ascribes importance to prefixes, which are arbitrary. If a generated input used different prefixes it would result in you failing to parse a document that is schema valid.

Comment: I have never seen prefixes being arbitrary.  They are always defined by the namespace in a specification the you can find at the URI for the xml file.  Occasionally the URL will be updated and the URL will be changed but the prefix of the definitions will stay the same so the format is backwards compatible with existing format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OutboundEvent` node is in a namespace but your code references it as if it wasn't. It is in the `urn:abb.com:assetsuite:IF:Event` namespace.

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:abb.com:assetsuite:IF:Event";
XNamespace bo = "urn:abb.com:assetsuite:IF:BO";
var businessObjects =
    document.Elements(ns + "OutboundEvent").Elements(bo + "BusinessObject");
```

Comment: It is in the default namespace actually. But yes, the default namespace should be defined and used as well.

Comment: Sorry, default namespace wasn't the right word for it. I forget what it's called. root? empty?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you define and use the default namespace for `OutboundEvent` element?

```
var document = XDocument.Load(path);
var ns = (XNamespace)"urn:abb.com:assetsuite:IF:Event";
var bo = (XNamespace)"urn:abb.com:assetsuite:IF:BO";

var businessobjects =
    from elements in document.Element(ns + "OutboundEvent")?.Elements(bo + "BusinessObject") 
        ?? Enumerable.Empty<XElement>()
    select elements;
```