# Sequence contains no elements when trying to grab xml node value from xml string

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

Please read the code bellow. There I am trying to grab all elements under the `<GetSellerListResponse>` node, then my goal is to grab `TotalNumberOfPages` value (currently it's 9 as you can see in the XML).

But my problem is I am getting an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'

Error screenshot is attached for better understanding. Can you tell me what's wrong the way I am trying to grab all elements? Also if possible can you tell how I can grab that 9 from `TotalNumberOfPage`?

Thanks in advance

C#:

```
var parsedXML = XElement.Parse(xml);
var AllElements = parsedXML.Descendants("GetSellerListResponse")
                           .Where(x => x.Attribute("xmlns").Value.Equals("urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"))
                           .First();
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetSellerListResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2018-06-20T17:26:29.518Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Version>1059</Version>
    <Build>E1059_CORE_APISELLING_18694654_R1</Build>
    <PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfPages>9</TotalNumberOfPages>
    </PaginationResult>
</GetSellerListResponse>
```

[image: Error pic]

Comment: You need to include the namespace.

Comment: implement namespace on it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46693262/34397

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-create-a-document-with-namespaces-linq-to-xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: your mistake is the usage of `XElement`: it is searching for matching elements in the children of `<GetSellerListResponse>`; that's why you are not getting any result. Change `XElement.Parse(xml);` to `XDocument.Parse(xml);`, then the following snippets will work.

You could simply check for the local name:

```
var AllElements = parsedXML.Descendants().First(x => x.Name.LocalName == "GetSellerListResponse");
```

I would suggest to use `XDocument` instead of `XElement` for `parsedXML`, because you could shorten the above query to `var AllElements = parsedXML.Root;`

Another thing you could try is prepending the namespace:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents";
var AllElements = parsedXML.Descendants(ns + "GetSellerListResponse").First();
```

To answer the question "how to get the number of pages":

```
var pages = AllElements.Element(ns + "PaginationResult").Element(ns + "TotalNumberOfPages").Value;
```

Comment: After using XDocument.Parse(xml) it goes well but how can i grab  TotalNumberOfPages then?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `XmlDocument` class from `System.Xml`.

Try the code below:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<GetSellerListResponse xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\"><Timestamp>2018-06-20T17: 26:29.518Z</Timestamp><Ack>Success</Ack><Version>1059</Version><Build>E1059_CORE_APISELLING_18694654_R1</Build><PaginationResult><TotalNumberOfPages>9</TotalNumberOfPages></PaginationResult></GetSellerListResponse>");
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("TotalNumberOfPages");
```

In this case, your `nodeList` will have just the one element for `TotalNumberOfPages` and you can access the value by checking

```
nodeList.FirstOrDefault().InnerText
```

Comment: No; you should use XElement, which has a much simpler API.

Comment: XmlDocument is compatible with versions of .NET 3 and lower. It is a programmers choice which one to use. I have used both XmlDocument and XDocument on different projects and have had success with both. This answer should resolve the original question.